# Should fetching data be a separate function?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm a beginner in `JS` and I have a question about best practice. I have a few functions that call the same `API` but do different things with data when data returns. I know that for repeat code we are supposed to create a new function, but does it make sense to create a new function just for fetching data?

I have to repeat it at least 4 times, something like this:

```
showAllBooks(user){
  fetch(`url`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
            //show all books for user
    });
});


showShortestBooks(user){
  fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
            //map through data and show shortest books in user's library
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: Looks like  `showAllBooks` needs `paging` stuffs while `shortestBooks` is `totalBytes`. In that case, you may only need one call with parameterized context depending on what you need and map them accordingly as `Book[]` model in the FE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things :

1. Maybe the server responding should take care of the calculation part of the shortest. Since you have two specific cases, I would probably move the responsibility of calculation out from 'views' and send it to the models, that is if you do have control over the server.
2. If you really are going to use the same and prefer to do overhead calculations on the front-end, you should probably have a method that makes the request and call that method in both the above methods. Basically wrap the fetch('url') part in a separate method like getBooks and just call getBooks() inside your methods. Based on your comfort you can use promises or callbacks (promises for the win \m/)

Comment: I don't have access to the server. Thank you! That's what I wanted to know!